# Can my laptop's hardware configuration be the reason that I get only 13601 digits of 1000000th term of fibonacci series?

Tags: python, iteration, fibonacci, hardware

I was trying to calculate 1000000th term of fibonaci series but my laptop took 22 seconds approximately to calculate 13601 digits. what could be the problem? it's the code or my hardware?

Hardware configuration:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20GHz   2.20 GHz
- Ram: 10gb
- Windows 10 64bit

Code:

```
import decimal
import math
def formulaFibWithDecimal(n):
    decimal.getcontext().prec = 80000

    root_5 = decimal.Decimal(5).sqrt()
    phi = ((1 + root_5) / 2)

    a = ((phi ** n) - ((-phi) ** -n)) / root_5

return round(a)

print(formulaFibWithDecimal(1000000))
```

Comment: It's both the code and your hardware, but it's unlikely that you can buy hardware that can run the same code *much* faster.

Comment: ...which is to say, better hardware might run 2x or 3x faster, but if what you want is 1000x faster, you need a better algorithm.

Comment: @marc_s can you tell me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: @PlanetofSeekers, ...I'd suggest you start by looking up a heavily optimized implementation and learning from that. "What's wrong with the code" isn't really the right way to look at it. There's nothing "wrong" with a bubble sort, but a quicksort will outperform it dramatically over a large dataset, even in the absence of implementation flaws in either.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions, I'll definitely act upon that. 